# Why can't I find elements on a pop-up window using selenium webdriver for python after successfully switching windows in firefox?

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

**I cannot find any elements in a new window, even after applying a long wait**

Using a firefox browser, I am able to use selenium to click on a link that opens a new window.Then I switch to the new window after looking up the window handle.

```
winHandles = browser.window_handles
NewWindow = browser.window_handles[1]
browser.switch_to_window(NewWindow)
```

I know that I am switched to the correct window because I am able to maximize the new window that popped up when I clicked on the link.

```
browser.maximize_window()
```

What could be going wrong that is preventing me from being able to find elements and how can I fix it?

Comment: Could it be that the window contains another frame to which you haven't switched ? Maybe if you could post the HTML code of the new window, we could inspect it further.

Comment: What have you tried and what was the result? Please read the help topics on how to ask a good question. You need to research your own issue, find code samples, etc. and write your own code to solve the issue. If you do all that and still can't figure it out, then come back and edit your question and add notes from the research you did, the code you have tried, and what the result was... any error messages, etc.

Answer (score 0):

As sagarwadhwa1 suggested in their comment, the window may switch without switching to the expected frame. You can find the correct frame by name or index and switch to it.

```
 browser.switch_to.frame(1)
```